# VS 2008 hangs(slow) when I select "File > Open > Web Site..."

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I try to select the following "File > Open > Web Site" or use the shortcut key "Shift + Alt + O" (which does the same), Visual Studio 2008 hangs with the loading mouse icon for about 8-10 seconds then the file.

But if I do "File > Open > Project/Solution.." or "File > Open > File..." the explorer window comes up in under a second, instantly most times.

Computer Specs:
Windows 7 x64
Visual Studio 2008 Pro Edition with Service Pack 1

Intel Core2 Due e6420 @ 3.2GHz
4GB DDR2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found [this hotfix](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958094) which took care of the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

i think this is coming because of your are loading your website from localhost. Openinf Project or Solution opens its as a general file opening process, but when you open a website it has some internal processing, which is displayed on screen via some message connecting localhost or opening web

Comment: If it satisfies you mark it as answer and vote it Good or Bad. Thanks

Comment: I haven't actually got to the point of loading the website, the long pause comes when I select "File > Open > Web Site" which should display the "Open Web Site" file explorer.

When it does reach this screen I can open a website pretty much instantly.

Comment: Ya, Its taking 2-3 secs on my machine too. I thinks its a normal process, bug in VS. It is not going to harm your computer. Keep on updating you VS with latest update. Hope it will get fixed by MS

Comment: if it satisfies you mark it as answer and vote it Good or Bad. Thanks